# Regex for string with dots

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation

I am trying to create a regex for validation of strings which expected to be between `{{ }}` and may contain dots in the middle, for example:`{{boy}}`, `{{boy.age}}`, `{{family.boy.age}}`. This should not be validated: `boy.age.` (because of the dot at the end.

For now I am having this: `/\{\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}\}/` which accepts only strings between double curly braces.

Tried to play with [this web site](http://regex101.com/), but couldn't make it work (no experience with regex).

Comment: A dot can be matched with `\.`. What other piece of information is missing ?

Comment: Hard to tell with so fuzzy requirements but you may want `/\{\{\s*\w[\.\w]*\w\s*\}\}/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\{\{(\w+\.)*\w+\}\}
```

If you need spaces, use the below:

```
\{\{\s*(\w+\.)*\w+\s*\}\}
```

Comment: Almost. Use `*` instead of `+`, otherwise it won't accept `{{boy}}`.

Comment: @dystroy In fairness, the optional spaces were not mentioned anywhere in the text of the question, the only time we see them is in the OP's attempt at a regex.

Comment: if there are spaces before the string, or after the string it wont work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the below regex,

```
\{\{\s*\w+[\w\.]*\w+\s*\}\}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xK2uJ5/2)

Comment: this one is working with spaces before the string begins, which I need. Thanks.

Comment: Note that {{a}} isn't valid with this regex (which might be good or not for you).

Comment: Better if it would... is it possible?

Comment: @vlio20 Yes : the other answer

Comment: @dystroy does the a single character means a string?

Comment: i mean `{{a}}`. Did you want to match a string with single character inside? @vlio20